# How to respond to "talk to you tomorrow"

Tags: greetings

I wonder how to respond to the sentence "talk to you tomorrow" if we are communicating via text message.

Is it ok to respond with "See you tomorrow"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when communicating via text one can say either "talk to you tomorrow" or "see you tomorrow".

Saying "see you tomorrow" means "see you *online* tomorrow" (even if you are not online at the same time).

It is expected that you will communicate further then, just as saying "see you tomorrow" for in-person interaction conveys the expectation that you will speak with one another, *not* the expectation that you will meet, stare at each other without speaking for some time, and then leave. Although that could also apply to some interactions. ;-)